# HTMLunit iterate nodes

Tags: java, htmlunit

I try iterate html nodes and getting information from this nodes.

This is html example:

```
<div class="less1">
  <h4>Test name 1</h4>
  <div>
     <div id="email">test1@test.com</div>
     <div id="email">test2@test.com</div>
     <div id="email">test3@test.com</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="less1">
  <h4>Test name 2</h4>
  <div>
     <div id="email">test_name1@test.com</div>
     <div id="email">test_name2@test.com</div>
     <div id="email">test_name3@test.com</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="less1">
  <h4>Test name 3</h4>
  <div>
     <div id="email">test_name_3@test.com</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="less1">
  <h4>Test name 4</h4>
</div>
```

This is my code example.

```
final List<HtmlListItem> nodes = htmlPage.getByXPath("//*[@class=\"less1\"]");

for (HtmlListItem node: nodes) {
   final List<?> divs = node.getByXPath("//h4/text()");
}
```

"divs" List size is always 4.

Is it possible get only 1 result from current node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get only the first matching element use `getFirstByXPath`:

```
final List<?> divs = node.getFirstByXPath("//h4/text()");
```

If you need a specific element by index:

```
final Object div = node.getByXPath("//h4/text()").get(index);
```

**UPDATE**

Maybe the problem is the usage of an absolute xpath.
Try to use a relative path on every node:

```
String text = node.getByXPath("h4/text()");
List<String> emails = node.getByXPath("div/div");
```

Otherwise you can extract data from every node exploring the child nodes

```
for (HtmlListItem node: nodes) {
    NodeList children = node.getChildNodes();
    for (int i = 0; i < children.getLength(); i++) {
       Node child = children.item(i);
       /** extract data from child **/
    }       
}
```

Comment: Yes, you can do it, but I want get almost another information inside this div. I updated html example. I want get for 1 node text from <h4> tag and also all emails from elements with id "email"

Comment: I just see that you didn't specified a relative xPath. Try to use node.getByXPath("h4/text()")

Comment: List<String> emails = node.getByXPath("div/div");  <- this is work. Thx